# Spring Data for Couchbase - increments the numerical value of special counter document

Tags: java, spring-boot, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I want to increments the numerical value of special counter document,
Obtain the id from counter document and increment it

```
com.couchbase.client.java.Bucket bucket;
JsonLongDocument joCounter = bucket.counter(docKey, 1);
```

but I don't know how to instantiate the bucket object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our documentation for the Java client shows how to connect to a Couchbase cluster and open a bucket:

https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/current/start-using-sdk.html